# App Crashed at launch, rejected by Apple

Tags: ios, swift

I recently updated my app to Swift 4 and made a few changes but for some reason Apple rejects my app because it crashes on an iPad on iOS 10.2... Unfortunately I can only test my app in the iPad Simulator, iPhone simulators and two real iPhones, so I can't test it on a real iPad.

They sent me a crash log, I used a command to Symbolicate the crash (from here: https://medium.com/@nikhilmshchs/symbolicating-ios-crash-reports-e97ad0d6b4dc)

The was the result from the last call from my code :

```
specialized closure #1 in ScannerViewController.setUpViews() (in QR Code Reader) (ScannerViewController.swift:595)
```

And this is the line 595 of that method:

```
case .auto: self.flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "FlashAuto"), for: .normal)
```

This is part of the method:

```
...
self.flashButton.isEnabled = self.captureDevice?.hasTorch ?? false
self.flashButton.isHidden = true

self.switchCameraButton.isHidden = true

switch UserDefaultsManager.torchModeState {
    case .on: self.turnTorch(.on)
    case .off: self.turnTorch(.off)
    case .auto: self.flashButton.setImage(#imageLiteral(resourceName: "FlashAuto"), for: .normal)
}
```

**More info:**
This method is called inside a `DispatchQueue.main.async` call, inside `awakeFromNib()`. The app works perfectly on my iPhone 7 Plus with iOS 11.0 GM and also works on an iPhone 6s with iOS 10.3.3.

I contacted a friend to test the app on a real iPad, but still I don't know why the app should crash on that device and not on my devices...

Maybe I have to set the button image before I hide the button instead of after, but I don't know...

**EDIT:**

I also check if the device has torch or not:

Inside `self.turnTorch()`:

```
if device.hasTorch, device.isTorchAvailable, device.isTorchModeSupported(mode) {...}
```

And inside `flashButtonAction()`:

```
guard let device = captureDevice, device.hasTorch, device.isTorchAvailable else { return }
```

**EDIT 2:**

After some answers, I manually checked (using **`UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom`**) if the device is an **iPad**, and if it is, that it should not use the torch... this seems to work fine because Apple hasn't rejected the new build :)

Comment: Are you sure that's not a OS typo?
Maybe some feature that was changed from 10.2 to 10.3.
You can deploy your app to iOS 10.3 + versions

Comment: Mm maybe, but I deployed my app to 9.0 or above before and in this version is 10.0 or above... And I didn't have this problem before :/

Comment: I'm saying that because I've once had an issue because I wasn't checking the OS architecture properly with the `arch(x86_64)` and it was rejected. Be aware of the action sheet presentations, you've to point to the presentation button as well. I'm saying that because you're issue only seems to be triggered on iPad.
Have you tried on any other iPad ?

Comment: On any button/item that requires a presentation I use the "popoverPresentationController" and it works on the iPad simulator

Comment: hmm... did you implement a singleton shared instance in your UserDefaultsManager ? Somehow it seems to crash when you're setting up the views. Be sure your user defaults are pointing to the correct location, somehow it may not find your path and if so, the `torchModeState` doesn't fire and it may cause a crash error.

Comment: Since the paths are different in various devices, the OS is supposed to find it properly, but it may be corrupted on the initial setup, see if you can do atomic writing to be sure the settings were properly set

Comment: In that case I use "UserDefaults.standard.set" to set tine rawValue of the torchMode and I use `defaults.object(forKey:)` to get the value... Oops, now I realise I can use `default.string(forKey:)` instead... Maybe I should try that

Comment: Be aware that if you use `string(forKey:)` and you're trying to fetch some binary data it may crash. Since you have `bool(forKey:)` as well. I've encountered in the past weird errors when fetching `NSData` from the UserDefaults and to avoid that I've moved to `FMDB` to use `SQL` and fetch `BLOB` files. I feel more secure that way

Comment: Yes, but in this case I save and fetch strings. I think I can test the app on a real iPad on Monday, I hope I can reproduce the crash

Comment: I've an old iPad mini here with me, but it's on iOS 9.3.2 , If you don't solve you're issue until monday, I have another iPad 4th gen with iOS 10.3 that I help you testing that through testflight if you wish so and you'll get the callback crash-log from Apple. DM me here or at Twitter if you need any further help with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPad simply doesn't have the camera flash.  So you can't use it.  If you are using `AVCaptureDevice` or something similar, you must make sure that the app won't access the auto flash mode.  Or the app will crash.

```
// Example //
class CameraViewController: BasicViewController, AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var flashSegcontrol: UISegmentedControl! // flashSegcontrol

    func snapPicture() {
        let settingsForMonitoring = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
        if flashSegcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 0 {
            if !isDeviceIpad() {
                settingsForMonitoring.flashMode = .on
            } else {
                settingsForMonitoring.flashMode = .off
            }
        }
        else if flashSegcontrol.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
            settingsForMonitoring.flashMode = .off
        }
        else {
            if !isDeviceIpad() {
                settingsForMonitoring.flashMode = .auto
            } else {
                settingsForMonitoring.flashMode = .off
            }
        }
        settingsForMonitoring.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true
        settingsForMonitoring.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = false
        imagePhotoOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settingsForMonitoring, delegate: self as AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate)    
    }

    func isDeviceIpad() -> Bool {
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiom.pad {
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, is not that issue:
Inside `self.turnTorch()`: `if device.hasTorch, device.isTorchAvailable, device.isTorchModeSupported(mode) {...}`
And inside `flashButtonAction()`: `guard let device = captureDevice, device.hasTorch, device.isTorchAvailable else { return }`

Comment: Actually... for some reason, even though I checked if the device had torch or not, checking if the device is an iPad is the only thing that seemed to work, so I guess is solved now

Comment: That's good to hear.  I got my iPhone/iPad app rejected half a year for this auto flash mode thing, actually.  Anyway, good luck with your app.